# Getting access to parameter inside a string being executed with 'load'

Tags: lua

I would like to know if there's a way for the 'load' function to get a variable value from a local variable instead of a global variable ?

Say that I've got a string like this 'trade.version == 2' that I want to execute with the 'load' function inside a function taking the trade as parameter.

```
function doTest( trade, test )
  -- inside the string 'test', I would like that any reference to 'trade'
  -- refer to the function parameter instead of a global variable
  if ( assert(load("return "..test))() ) then
    -- do something
  end
end

a_userdata = { version = 2 }
-- Calling the function above
doTest( a_userdata , "trade.version == 2" )

[string "return trade.version == 2"]:1: attempt to index global 'trade' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    [string "return trade.version == 2"]:1: in main chunk
    stdin:2: in function 'doTest'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

As a workaround, I have defined a global variable and it's working pretty fine.
But I would like to avoid this global variable.

Thank you very much

Comment: What Lua version you plan to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function doTest( trade, test )
  -- inside the string 'test', I would like that any reference to 'trade'
  -- refer to the function parameter instead of a global variable
  if assert(load("local trade = ...; return "..test))(trade) then
    -- do something
    print('Yes, version equals to 2')
  end
end

a_userdata = { version = 2 }
-- Calling the function above
doTest( a_userdata , "trade.version == 2" )
```

Comment: great ! Thank you very much